# Soundproofing an open stairwell against downstair noise

Tags: doors, attic, stairs, door-frame, sound-proofing

### I'm trying to dampen the sound that comes up the stairwell by installing a new wall and a soundproof blanket.

We currently have a half-wall that I'll be extending up to the ceiling.

And that would leave me with a doorway, but without a traditional frame to mount the blanket too using velcro.

I've found the best way to block sound would be to mount a velcro frame to really seal the gaps.  Something like:

[image: Velcro blanket]

But the current space I have doesn't have a "frame." Here's a picture of what I'm planning to do (it's a 3-D iPhone scan so pardon the quality):

### Before the project

[image: Before]

### After the project (mock up)

[image: After]

### My main concern is Velcro mounting the blanket

The goal is to make this non-permanent. Easy to attach and detach.

After I extend the left-side wall, I'll have somewhere to mount Velcro. But that leaves the top, right, and bottom sides un-mountable.

How can I go about adding a top and right side of the "doorframe" to mount Velcro to? I'm thinking L brackets, but would that be strong enough to hold a 12 lb blanket?

Comment: You may want to try a temporary rig before committing to this proposal. Over that much surface area, I don't think a blanket is likely to make a great deal of difference. You may also face fire code issues.

Comment: Something wrong with a door?

Comment: Can't see your pics right now, but can you just mount one side of the Velcro (I'd suggest the loop side) to the walls & ceiling and the other side (loop side) to the blanket? Why to you need a frame to attach the Velcro?

Answer (score 0):

Frame the opening to give you something to attach to.  A 2x4 frame with wallboard around it would probably look best, but just a painted 2x2 would give you enough to velcro to.